# JMS and Oracle AQ

Tags: oracle, jms, oracle-aq

Would anyone be able to point me to some sample java code that shows me to how to listen on an Oracle AQ Queue?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basics.  The conn variable contains a regular JDBC Connection class already connected to the DB.

```
QueueConnection queueConnection = AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory. 
        createQueueConnection(conn); 
QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection. 
        createQueueSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED); 
Queue queue=queueSession.createQueue("my_oracle_queue"); 
QueueReceiver receiver= queueSession.createReceiver(queue); 
queueConnection.start(); 
Message message=receiver.receive();
```

The oracle specific classes like AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory are in the package oracle.jms.

Comment: Hi JOTN, thanks for this. WOuld have a sample that continually polls a queue?

Comment: You don't need to poll because the process will block waiting for a message.  If you don't want to block, look at the setMessageListener method of QueueReceiver to use a callback.

Comment: Hi JotnMany thaks for your input. I tried out your solution in our webapp and it works perfectly